# The xamarin.ios screen doesn't update

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, tableview

I have created a project using xamarin.ios from Visual Studio(ios 13) from my mac mini device.
I have deleted storyboard files.

I have Main.cs, AppDelegate.cs, TableView.cs and TableSource.cs files.

Main.cs:

```
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace LabelWrap
{
    public class Application
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
            // you can specify it here.
            //UIApplication.Main(args, null, typeof(AppDelegate));


            try
            {
                UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.cs:

```
using System;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace LabelWrap
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        UIWindow window;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

            window.RootViewController = new TableView();
            
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

TableSource.cs:

```
using System;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace LabelWrap
{
    public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
    {

        string[] TableItems;
        string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";

        public TableSource(string[] items)
        {
            TableItems = items;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return TableItems.Length;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
            string item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];

            //if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
            if (cell == null)
            {
                cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier);
            }

            cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

TableView.cs:

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace LabelWrap
{
    public partial class TableView : UITableViewController
    {
        UITableView table;

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
            table = new UITableView(View.Bounds); // defaults to Plain style
            string[] tableItems = new string[] { "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Flower Buds", "Legumes", "Bulbs", "Tubers" };
            table.Source = new TableSource(tableItems);
            table.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;
            Add(table);
        }
    }  
}
```

My project runs succesfully, but the Ios emulator(ios 13), when I open the application, shows a black Screen.
When I put a breakpoint in my code it seems that everything is executed correctly, but I don't see any differences on the screen.

Have I missed something in the code or is there a mistake? So that the results I have written in the tableView can be seen on the screen

Comment: Have you tried deleting ```UIApplicationSceneManifest``` key in the info.plist?

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want this [effect](https://imgur.com/a/h5Ap4lw)?

1. Open VS for MAC and create a new project(choose [iOS Application](https://imgur.com/a/XDcOYM6))
2. Move your code to this project.
3. Open info.plist and delete the value of `Launch screen interface file base name` like [this](https://imgur.com/a/avDfB80).
4. Then you can choose to delete storyboard file or not.